# curl_multi_exec returning empty arrays

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

I have been using the following function to make asynchronous curl posts:

```
function curl_post_multi($urls){
    $curl_arr = array();
    $num_urls = count($urls);
    $mh = curl_multi_init();
    for($i= 0; $i < $num_urls; $i++){
        $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_URL, $urls[$i]);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curl_arr[$i]);
    }

    $running = null;
    do{
        curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    }while($running > 0);
    $results = array();
    for($i= 0; $i < $num_urls; $i++){
        $results[] = curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $curl_arr[$i]);
    }
    curl_multi_close($mh);
    return $results;
}
```

I've just now noticed that it is often only returning results from the first URL, or no results at all. I've played around with about 100 configurations of this function. The results are empty arrays, and curl_error($curl_arr[$i]) is empty, so I'm not sure where to start looking for what's wrong. I know the URLS are correct because if I do back to back regular curls it works fine.

Comment: might it be the urls behaving properly? it seems odd to request a webpage via post, without sending any post variables, even though that's valid. It works ok for me.

Comment: What's odd about it? I've always preferred a POST to a GET when I could help it, though I'm not sure when or why I learned to do it that way...

No, the URL's are fine. Like I said they all work fine with a regular POST. I'm starting to think it's something lower level, or something on the other end of the POST.

Comment: This looks easy enough to try with only one `curl_exec()` to modify the url and print the $result. IOW, try the single curl for results. Maybe the opts are not correctly configured.

Comment: Again... "Like I said they all work fine with a regular POST." AKA a curl exec with all the same opts but without using multi. Works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Your do-while loop never runs. $running is never > 1, as it's set to null on the previous line.

Comment: This is incorrect. Please see the manual for curl_multi_exec
http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php $running is set by that function in the do section of the loop.